# Real analysis reference for statistician

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, reference-request, self-learning

I'm a undergraduate statistics student, I think that learn Real Analysis can be useful to me in some points, can anyone suggest a introductory book for self-study ?

I'm already multivariate calculus, algebra linear, and others math courses.

Someone said to me to start with [Analysis: With an Introduction to Proof](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131481010)  and then move to [By Walter Rudin The Principles of Mathematical Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00N4EILRI). Is that a good idea, or I shoud start directly with Rudin?

Comment: I used the book "Understanding Analysis" by Stephen Abbott for my undergraduate analysis class. It's a nice introduction for a first-time student studying analysis

Comment: I would recommend "Introduction to Analysis" by Rosenlicht. It's cheap, easy to follow, and compact (no pun intended).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard undergraduate text for real analysis is Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* (affectionately referred to as "Baby Rudin" since he wrote it when he was quite young).

Another text I enjoyed was Serge Lang's *Undergraduate Analysis*.

I think they're both have their pros and cons but are ultimately both fine books for first learning some rudimentary real analysis.

Comment: I thought the term "baby Rudin" os to distinguish it from another more advanced Rudin textbook in analysis.  Baby Rudin is great as a textbook for a course with an instructor.  But it is sometimes quite terse, so may not be good for self-study.

Comment: @GEdgar I didn't personally have trouble reading through Baby Rudin as a first analysis textbook (I did take it in a class but didn't go to any of the lectures). It was definitely a little hard at times, but I think that only helped me learn. Some people may not be as persistent, etc.